# Using Celery + Flask + Docker + Message Broker

Tags: python, docker, web-scraping, celery

I am working on a scraping project and I want my python scrapers to run when I invoke an API call to my Flask server. I have an idea of using celery workers to do the scraping and use the Flask server as a gateway and for checking of the running status of the scraper worker. I just have some few question regarding this setup.

1. What is the recommended message broker and backend for celery worker/scraper?
2. Is it possible to only make the scraping job run once. I mean once I call the API then when I call it again it would not start another job, unless there is no existing running job, instead will just return the status of the existing running job? I only plan to run the scrapers once a day.
3. If that is possible how can I do it using Celery? Multiple tasks?
4. Is it also possible to run all of this in the cloud and only turn on the celery worker server when I call the API?

If my idea is too complicated for my use case. Do you have any recommendation on what can I use to optimize my project?

I already have a docker-compose.yml and running celery workers. I just want to optimize and improve my setup.